# Why is my button color not changing on command?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I "made"  this script:

```html
<script>
export default {
    name: "Form"
}

var backRGB = document.getElementById("color").value;
document.getElementById("color").onchange = function() {
  backRGB = this.value;
  console.log(backRGB);
  document.getElementById("orgButton").color = backRGB;
}
</script>
```

It supposedly checks if the color picker with 'color' has changed and if it does it changes the button 'orgButon' to the color that was picked. However, it's not working. I think that even the console.log isn't working.

Here's the template:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="formulario">
            <h1>Criar Organização</h1>
            <form>
                <div><input class="long" type="text" name="orgName" id="orgName" placeholder="Nome" minlength="5" maxlength="20"></div>
                <div>
                    <input class="short" type="text" name="orgAbb" id="orgAbb" placeholder="Abreviatura" minlength="3" maxlength="4">
                    <input type="color" id="color" value="#f6b73c">
                </div>
                <input class="button" type="button" id="orgButton" value="Criar">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The code above is all in Form.vue.

Answer (score 0):

If the JS is above the HTML, it will fail because `document.getElementById("color")` doesn't exist yet so it can't set its onchange event handler.

The following code worked for me:

```
    <div>
    <div class="formulario">
        <h1>Criar Organização</h1>
        <form>
            <div><input class="long" type="text" name="orgName" id="orgName" placeholder="Nome" minlength="5" maxlength="20"></div>
            <div>
                <input class="short" type="text" name="orgAbb" id="orgAbb" placeholder="Abreviatura" minlength="3" maxlength="4">
                <input type="color" id="color" value="#f6b73c">
            </div>
            <input class="button" type="button" id="orgButton" value="Criar">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
var backRGB = document.getElementById("color").value;

document.getElementById("color").onchange = function() {
    backRGB = this.value;
    console.log(backRGB);
    document.getElementById("orgButton").style.backgroundColor = backRGB;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using vue.js in your code. This solution makes use of [two-way binding with v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Handling-User-Input)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="color" v-model="color">
    <p>{{ color }}</p>
    <button :style="{color}">BUTTON</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      color: ""
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

[Open this codepen for demonstration](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-merkle-l3v59?file=/src/App.vue)

EDIT: more info on reactive styles [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)